# The sum of these 9! determinants is?

Tags: combinatorics, determinant

[image] (image is attached for those who think I have changed the statement of the question while copying from the book)

### Chose any 9 distinct integers. These 9 integers can be arranged to from 9! determinants each of order 3. The sum of these 9! determinants is?

---

**My approach**

For any Δ, there exist -Δ in arrangements

∴ sum = 0

*I am looking for another approach!*

Comment: I think your reasoning is sound. It's zero, confirmed by brute force in Mathematica with `Total[Det[ArrayReshape[#, {3, 3}]] & /@ Permutations[Range[9]]]`. We're lucky that 9! isn't so big that brute force is actually possible.

Comment: @flinty now to generalize to the choice of $n^2$ numbers forming $(n^2)!$ determinants, it's impossible to brute-force. I suppose the point was to do some reasoning, which OP did correct, as the answer below suggested.

Comment: You could make the statement better by copying without any change to the statement in the book.

Comment: I have not change any Statement! for your kind information

Comment: @Anthony OP asked for 3x3, not to generalize. For 3x3, brute force is a perfectly valid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pair up the determinants:  For any matrix $M$, define $M'$ by flipping the first and second rows.  Then $\det(M)+\det(M')=0$.  To avoid duplications, sum over all $M$ such that $m_{11} \lt m_{21}$.  Then each matrix appears exactly once as either $M$ or $M'$.

Comment: That's exactly OP's solution?

Comment: Why this question is voted to be closed?

Comment: Thanks @Robert Shore .Big Help!.So there should be 9!/2 such  pairs exist

Comment: Yes, and this proof works for  $n^2$ distinct numbers with $n \gt 2$ (so that there exist a first and second row to flip).  If you find the answer helpful, upvotes and acceptances are always welcome.

Comment: fora 2 order matrix it can be happen with 4 distinct elements

Comment: @AmartyaRoy  There are close-voters who simply vote to close because a question is short.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said $n \geq 2.$

Comment: @Batominovski I am amazed to see, for some people size of question matters rather than it's quality